# round robin tournament with 20 contestants and some funky conditions about the wins of each team

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Suppose $20$ teams play a round robin tournament and the number of games won by each team is a perfect square, and in addition, the number of teams winning $9$ games is the same as the number of teams winning $16$ games. Given that there are no ties, how many teams have $16$ wins?

Of course I didn't just post this question with out diligence I ran into glitches at the end but think I was on right track. If you suppose $x$ teams and $y$ teams have $16$ and $9$ wins respectively then the $19-(x+y)$ teams automatically have wins that are $9y-16x$. Some how yet I'm not seeing it yet is a contradiction as far as the 'no ties' condition.

Comment: Please use MathJax when writing up your question. Also, it is more likely to be answered if you pay attention to typos and grammar- if it looks like you put time into your question, other people are more likely to put time into answering it!

Comment: Can you find the total number of games from the number of teams? This is the number  of wins that are to be distributed to $20$ teams. Of these teams, the same number have won $16$ and $9$ games. Now, if $x$ teams have won $16$ (or $9$) games, then $2x$  teams get $25x$ wins in total. The question is : for what $x$ can you distribute "number of wins" $- 25x$ wins amongst the remaining $20-2x$ teams, so that every team gets either $4,1$ or $0$ wins?

Comment: Try to use MathJax to typeset equations. I can see that you did not do so in at least some if your previous posts as well.

Comment: i dont know how 

Comment: im a math nerd not a computer geek

Comment: I posted a question with similar conditions to [puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75/round-robin-tournament) but the question is not the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be at most $7$ teams with $16$ points.  All the teams with $16$ points play a tournament among themselves.  If there are $8$ teams that might have $16$ points they each play $7$ games against the others and some must lose $4$ games, only scoring $15$.

There are $190$ games, so $190$ total points.  If there are $6$ teams with each of $16$ and $9$ points, they account for $150$ points.  There are then $150$ points accounted for among $12$ teams.  The other $8$ teams can only score $4$ points each for a total of $32$, which is not enough, so $x$ is at least $7$.

We have our answer, but we can go on.  There are $7$ teams with $16$ points each.  They go $3-3$ against each other and beat all $13$ other teams.  There are $7$ teams with $9$ each.  That leaves $15$ points for the other $6$ teams, which must be $3$ with $4$ points and $3$ with $1$.  The teams with $1$ go $1-1$ against each other and lose all the rest of the games.  The teams with $4$ go $1-1$ against each other, beat the $1$ point teams, and lose all the rest.  The teams with $9$ go $3-3$ against each other, beat all the $4$s and $1$s, and lose to all the $16$s

Comment: Ross this : " There are 190 games, so 190 total points. If there are 6 teams with each of 16 and 9 points, they account for 150 points. There are then 150 points accounted for among 12 teams. The other 8 teams can only score 4 points each for a total of 32, which is not enough, so x is at least 7 " made perfect sense and is crystal clear ( im still going to reread and understand the other two big statements u made ) but this is the proof by way of contradiction i was thinking of and this problem seemed to be whispering to me prove me  bwoc 